# Error creating bean with name 'formUserController'

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

i was developing a web app using springmvc when i keep getting an error ,here's my files:

FormUserController.java:

```
import com.ensat.service.UtilisateurServiceImp;
import com.ensat.model.Utilisateur;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
@Controller
public class FormUserController {

    private UtilisateurServiceImp userService;

    @Autowired(required = true)
    public FormUserController(UtilisateurServiceImp USI) {
        this.userService = USI;
    }

    private Map<Integer, Utilisateur> UtilisateurMap = new HashMap<>();

    @RequestMapping(value = "/addUser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String submit(
            @ModelAttribute("Utilisateur") Utilisateur utilisateur,
            BindingResult result, ModelMap model) {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "error";
        }
        model.addAttribute("nom", utilisateur.getNom());
        model.addAttribute("id", utilisateur.getIdUser());
        model.addAttribute("prenom", utilisateur.getPrenom());
        model.addAttribute("profession", utilisateur.getProfession());
        model.addAttribute("photo", utilisateur.getPhoto());
        model.addAttribute("msg", "Welcome to Island!");

        model.addAttribute("utilisateur", utilisateur);
        UtilisateurMap.put(utilisateur.getIdUser(), utilisateur);
        if (utilisateur.getIdUser() == 0) {
            //new person, add it
           this.userService.addService(utilisateur);

        } else {
            //existing person, call update
            this.userService.updateService(utilisateur);

        }

        return "listUser";
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/edit/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String editUtilisateur(
            @ModelAttribute("Utilisateur") Utilisateur utilisateur,
            BindingResult result, ModelMap model) {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "error";
        }
        model.addAttribute("nom", utilisateur.getNom());
        model.addAttribute("id", utilisateur.getIdUser());
        model.addAttribute("prenom", utilisateur.getPrenom());
        model.addAttribute("profession", utilisateur.getProfession());
        model.addAttribute("photo", utilisateur.getPhoto());

        UtilisateurMap.put(utilisateur.getIdUser(), utilisateur);
        this.userService.updateService(utilisateur);
        return "listUser";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/remove/{id}")
    public String removeUtilisateur(@PathVariable("idUser") int id) {
    this.userService.removeService(id);

        return "listUser";
    }
}
```

UtilisateurServiceImp.java:

```
import com.ensat.dao.UtilisateurDao;
import com.ensat.model.Utilisateur;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
public class UtilisateurServiceImp implements Services<Utilisateur> {
    @Autowired
    private UtilisateurDao UtilisateurDAO;

    public void setUtilisateurDAO(UtilisateurDao UtilisateurDAO) {
        this.UtilisateurDAO = UtilisateurDAO;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void addService(Utilisateur user) {
        this.UtilisateurDAO.saveUser(user);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void updateService(Utilisateur user) {
        this.UtilisateurDAO.UpdateUser( user);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public List<Utilisateur> listServices() {
        return this.UtilisateurDAO.getAllelements();
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Utilisateur getServiceById(Integer userId) {
        return this.UtilisateurDAO.listUserById(userId);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void removeService(Integer userId) {
        this.UtilisateurDAO.deleteUser(userId);
    }

}
```

my web.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

my dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">
       <mvc:annotation-driven />
<context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.ensat"></context:component-scan>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>




    <bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
          p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
          p:suffix=".jsp" />


    <bean name="indexController"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController"
          p:viewName="index" />


</beans>
```

when i keep getting this error

> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception lors
>   de l'envoi de l'évènement contexte initialisé (context initialized) à
>   l'instance de classe d'écoute (listener)
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener 
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'formUserController' defined in file
>   [C:\Users\admin\Documents\NetBeansProjects\PostUserProjet1\PostUserProjet1\target\PosUserProject-1.0-SNAPSHOT\WEB-INF\classes\com\ensat\Controller\FormUserController.class]:
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with
>   index 0 of type [com.ensat.service.UtilisateurServiceImp]: : No
>   qualifying bean of type [com.ensat.service.UtilisateurServiceImp]
>   found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as
>   autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {};
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type [com.ensat.service.UtilisateurServiceImp]
>   found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as
>   autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:747)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:185)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1114)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1017)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4738)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5181)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:586)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:460)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1586)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
>     at
>   com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
>     at
>   com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1460)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:906)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doGet(ManagerServlet.java:344)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:614)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Thanks in advance

Comment: may you post more detail about the exception? e.g. caused by or thr full stack trace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UtilisateurServiceImp` class is not a spring bean and can not be injected to `FormUserController` constructor. You must to add `@Component` annotation to it or define it in dispatcher-servlet.xml.